# Specifying time zone in when2meet

Tags: events, time-zone, when2meet

Is it possible to specify time zones in [when2meet](https://www.when2meet.com/)? I.e. when creating a new event, I would like to indicate in which time zone the proposed times are expressed.

Comment: Hi Franck. You (and others) may be interested in this related answer that I just posted on Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/90061/8503

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update 20 Feb 2018. From the developer:

> I've updated when2meet to now include support for scheduling events across multiple time zones. Each participant's time zones are automatically detected for newly created events. The grid is shown as appropriate for each user's time zone, including shifts due to daylight savings.

And indeed, if you visit https://www.when2meet.com/, there's now a "Time Zone" field with a drop-down list of time zones, and the current time zone has been detected.

What a great update!

Original answer:

<s>I had the same need and asked the developer (support@when2meet.com) the same question on 13-Jan-2015. The answer was:</s>

> At present, when2meet does not take timezones into account... Several users have requested more timezone-based functionality and I hope to add it soon.

Several workarounds suggested by the developer in the meantime:

- Include the time zone in the event title, e.g. "Conference Call (Eastern Time)"
- Tell participants the time zone when you send the invitation

Probably you'll want to do both. And then cross your fingers with me that the developer eventually gets enough free time to add time zone support. =)